# Storing huge matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, storage

I have `N x N` matrix of bytes with `N = 200,000,000`. I want to get value of `M[i, j]` in `O(1)` time, and store matrix on the hard drives more efficiently than `O(N*N)` memory. The matrix is not sparse, but the values are always between 0..255. Is it hopeless?

Comment: If you can isolate patterns (a chunk of a matrix) that repeat, you could create a meta matrix and then decompress that or use a method with a table when needed.  I'm not an expert with this, but I think that strategy could reduce your storage requirement.

Comment: Have you tried some benchmark with [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) ?

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix values are random - then yes you're screwed. You'll need a disk 200MB^2.

If the matrix has a pattern to it then it may be possible to store it. It will depend greatly on what you know about the matrix, and if there are safe transformations you can do on it.

One question I would have - are there regions of the matrix where the values don't matter? If so, I'd zero them out and not store them.